# PublicKeySizeInvalid error in decodePoint function output

Tags: haskell, cryptography, elliptic-curve

I am trying this function in GHCI,

```
import Data.ByteString.Char8
import Crypto.PubKey.ECIES 
import Crypto.ECC
import Data.Proxy

curve = Proxy :: Proxy Curve_X448

str = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
seed = Data.ByteString.Char8.pack str
d =  decodePoint curve seed
d
```

but it gives an error  `CryptoFailed CryptoError_PublicKeySizeInvalid`, what should be the size of `str`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the X448 curve, as the name suggests, the key size should be 448 bits, or 56 bytes:

```
-- import ...

curve = Proxy :: Proxy Curve_X448

seed = Data.ByteString.Char8.replicate 56 'a'
d = decodePoint curve seed
d
```

Prints out:

```
CryptoPassed (PublicKey "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa")
```